# How to pass arguments from VBA to Powershell script

Tags: vba, syntax, parameter-passing, powershell-4.0

I need to pass some arguments from VBA7 to Powershell script (version 4.0).  I was able to run the PS script by entering all the arguments manually in the Powershell Editor and run it to validate that the script works.  Here is the PS script:

```
param(
    $pw,
    $from ="",
    $to ="",
    $subject = "",
    $body = "",
    $file = "",
    $server = "imap.myserver.com",
    $port = 111
)

$pw = ConvertTo-SecureString $pw -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($from, $pw)

try{
    Send-MailMessage -From $from -to $to -SmtpServer $server -Body $body -Subject $subject -Attachments $file -Port $port -Credential $cred -ErrorAction Stop
    Exit 0;
    }
catch
    {
    Write-Host $error[0]
    Exit 1;
    }
```

For some reason when I call this script from VBA it doesn't work, I don't have any error message, I can see that Powershell is being called from the macro but nothing happens. Maybe the synthax is not correct? I have tried adding quotes here and there but no sucess. Here is a simplied version of the code:

```
Sub CallPowerShellWithArguments()

    Call Shell("powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass C:\Program Files (x86)\mailsend\send_reports.ps1 -pw Mypassword -from myemail1@mail.com -to myemail1@mail.com -subject MyEmail -body This is my test -file C:\mysql\test.tx")

End Sub
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need quotation marks around your parameters? E.g. the path? Try it like this: ""C:\Program Files (x86)\mailsend\send_reports.ps1""

Comment: Also, if you just copy-paste your code to a normal cmd window, does it run properly?

Comment: @vacip I did try to use double quotes, I get a syntax error.  And yes the code works in a cmd window. The issue really seems to be in the arguments passing

Comment: wait, what? if you get syntax error, then there is something wrong with your double quotes. syntax error in VBA, you mean? can you post what you have tried? also, this works withouth quotation marks? but there is a space in Program files. how is that possible? I'm baffled.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will be the correct answer but it's definitely something you can try. I would suggest providing the full path for PowerShell.exe. For example,

```
 C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```